# CSS selector when there is direct siblings

Tags: html, css

I need to target every contiguous `<br>` in css. Lemme explain. In my piece of code i have attached you can see one `<br>` tag. Then comes the text. After that three `<br>` tag then comes the text and it goes on.

My question is there is any css selector to select when there is continuous range of `<br>` is present. When there is three continuous `<br>` tag i want to select second and third `<br>` tag. When there is four continuous `<br>` tag i want to select second, third, fourth `<br>` tag. Any ways to achieve it with CSS

```css
div br:not(:first-child){
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    how can i select a DOM
    <br>
    which comes next to next
   <br>
   <br>
   <br>
    Any Idea please suggest
    <br>
    <br>
    Thanks 
</div>
```

Comment: Use `<p>` tag in making new line instead of `<br>`

Comment: @NelsonTan Thanks for your suggestion.But i want CSS selector to select it. Let it be any tag.

Comment: @Santosh Kumar You want to select the `<br>` tag using CSS SELECTOR?

Comment: S i want to select tag. Spare some time to read my question carefully. To get an clear view of which br tag to select

Comment: @SanthoshKumar Wrap your continuous `<br>` in a `<div>` and then use `div br + br { ... }` to style otherwise I think you can't. However I would suggest to look for some other approach as for me its not very cool.

Comment: I think you can't select `<br>` using CSS selectors that's why i'm suggesting to use `<p>` tag.

Comment: @NelsonTan. It is possible to select br using css

Comment: @MuhammadUsman. Any work around without adding an EXTRA DOM

Answer (score 0):

Don't use 
 if you don't want unnecessary space of a line. 
Instead you can use 



 or  because its automatically point the cursor to the next Line.